# WPF DataGrid wrapped by Grid won't scroll horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, datagrid

I'm trying to make my DataGrid scroll horizontally when the window is too small to display all of the columns. I'm using Grids to control the positioning of my elements. Can someone explain why the scrollbar isn't appearing and how I can fix it? I would prefer a XAML only solution if possible.

Here is my complete code. Feel free to critique anything weird you see because I'm new to WPF.

```
<Window x:Class="FBLAM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FBLAM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsMainMenu="True" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        Menu Goes Here
    </Menu>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid 
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              x:Name="MemberData" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              IsReadOnly="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
              CanUserAddRows="True" 
              CanUserSortColumns="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              BorderThickness="0" 
              Margin="0" 
              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="School" Binding="{Binding School}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Binding="{Binding State}" />
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Year Joined" Binding="{Binding YearJoined}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade" Binding="{Binding Grade}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount Owed" Binding="{Binding AmountOwed, StringFormat=C}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching around, I finally found the thing that was causing the problem and how to solve it.

Here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6750a6a-fc94-496e-9a94-10e48831a4d2/simply-want-auto-width-on-control-but-to-have-a-horizontal-scrollbar-if-parent-is-too-narrow?forum=wpf

I just need to put a ScrollViewer around the entire Grid. Talk about simple!

Much thanks to @d.mondada for getting me started on the right path.

Comment: This may work, but then you will technically have two ScrollViewers (one hidden). This is because DataGrid has its own built in ScrollViewer as part of its template.

Comment: @d.moncada True, but from what I've read so far, putting a datagrid inside a grid column with width auto effectively disables the horizontal scrolling that is built into the datagrid. The width auto means that the column will be as wide as it needs to be in order to not scroll, and that's the behavior I'm looking for when the window is larger than the datagrid, but not when the datagrid is larger than the window. Let me know if you find a way to keep auto from expanding larger than the window.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a `ColumnDefinition` that is bound to the `ActualWidth` of the `DataGrid`? Remove that. Also, move the `ScrollViewer` properties to the `DataGrid` itself.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" IsMainMenu="True" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            //menu items
        </Menu>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" 
                      Grid.Row="1" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      IsReadOnly="False" 
                      CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                      CanUserAddRows="True" 
                      CanUserSortColumns="True" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      SelectionMode="Single" 
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" 
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                      BorderThickness="0" 
                      Margin="0" 
                      GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    //10 columns here
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But it didn't totally fix the problem. At least the scrollbar is showing up now though. I had that binding thing because it was somehow keeping my datagrid from going off screen when I resize the window, however it seems to be covering up the problem that I'm having instead of solving it. When I remove it, the datagrid stays centered on the window but isn't achored to the sides of the window, so the scrollbar doesn't "catch" on the edges of the window. Basically, the scrollbar doesn't know how big my window is and just behaves similar to "overflow: hidden".

Comment: did you post the complete XAML so I can try and reproduce it on my side?

Comment: I had cut out the columns but I'll add those since you asked. It is updated

Comment: Don't worry about populating the datagrid with a data source, just as long as you can see the headers you'll be able to test the horizontal scroll bar.